# Active Directory using ldap in C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I have used `System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory` but when I tried to use `Domain.Name` or `Domain.GetDomain` methods, I get an error

> 'Domain' does not contain a definition for 'GetDomain'.

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DirectoryContext s = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, "my domain", "myuser", "mypass");
        Domain domain = Domain.GetDomain(s);

        Forest forest = domain.Forest;

        DomainCollection domains = forest.Domains;

        foreach (Domain objDomain in domains)
        {
             Response.Write(objDomain.Name.ToString());
             Response.Write("<br/>");
        }  
    }
}
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Since we really cannot see and read your screen - nor your mind - you'll need to **SHOW US** some of the relevant code!

Comment: using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;



public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DirectoryContext s=new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, "LDAP://ad360-dc1", "administrator", "Ad360@123");
        Domain domain = Domain.GetDomain(s);

          

        Forest forest = domain.Forest;

DomainCollection domains = forest.Domains;
foreach (Domain objDomain in domains)
{
    Response.Write(objDomain.Name.ToString());
    Response.Write("<br/>");
}  
    }
} @marc_s

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: done. help now  @marc_s

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domain.getdomain(v=vs.110).aspx), `GetDomain()` is a static method, which means it cannot be accessed outside of a static context - that is why you're getting that particular error. To prove this was the case, I just copied and pasted your code into a console app, which by default will be run from a static void method called `Main()` :

```
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;

namespace LDAPTEST
{
    public class Program
    {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             DirectoryContext s = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, "DC=hq,DC=xxxxxxxxx,DC=com", "TestUsername", "TestPassword");

             Domain domain = Domain.GetDomain(s);
             Forest forest = domain.Forest;
             DomainCollection domains = forest.Domains;

             foreach (Domain objDomain in domains)
             {
                  Console.Write("");
             }  
         }
     }
}
```

This will compile and run. However, since you're developing an Asp.Net web application, I would advise using the lower level `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` or even the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace to accomplish your task.

Comment: No problem - if this answered your question, please click the check mark below the point arrows on the answer. That way, others will know that this solved the issue.